# How to create a/ instantiate a constructor from one file to the main dart file in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am working on creating a hashMap for my flutter program and would like some input on it. As I created my hashMap in another dart file that is not the main dart file and I have no idea on how to connect it even when I created constrictors for the hashMaps. This is very important as the hashMap will be used on several files within the program hence why it is not in the main dart. Therefore I would like your guys input on how I could connect the two files.

This is part of my code:

main dart file:

```
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  //Always use Stateless first then use stateful or stateless widgets afterward
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //only used at the beginning of the program
      title: 'The Cafe',
      //just a title to the app it does not show for there is nothing telling it to show on the screen
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //takes out the ribbon at the top right corner of the screen and app
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          fontFamily: 'georgia',
          textTheme: TextTheme(headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 100))
        //controls the color of the very top part of the application
      ),
      home: StartPage(),
      //used to connect the Stateless widget to the Stateful widget below
    );
  }
}


class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartPageState createState() => _StartPageState();
}
// do not forget the } prior to this comment  if you do it will result in error and the program does not known why either

class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
  String value = "";

  //stating the string is not seen until you have started to compute the drop-downs
//have the drop down's take you to the item page
  //void main(){
  //HashMap map = new HashMap<String, double>();
   // LinkedHashMap linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<int, String>();
   // SplayTreeMap treeMap = new SplayTreeMap<int, String>();

  //}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('The Campus Cafe'),
        //where the main title is computed to be shown on the screen
        centerTitle: true,
        //centers the title
      ),
      body: Center(
        //This is Header that is after the main Title
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              //Header Container
              Expanded(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/campus-cafe-logo-350sidebar.png',)
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text("Our Menu",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                ),
              ),

              Expanded(
                //Expands is used to create a body if you want a header and body...can also be used for other things but at the moment this is all I know
                child: Column(

                  //there can be different types of Columns
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      //Padding is how far away one container or item is away from another as shown below
                      flex:3,
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        //items are basically like an array or list
                          items: [
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "1",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Grilled Cheese'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "2",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Grilled Ham & Cheese'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "3",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('BLT'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "4",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Western Chicken Sandwich'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "5",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Crispy Chicken Wrap'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "6",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Cheese Steak'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                          onChanged: (_value) => {
                            print(_value.toString()),
                            setState(() {
                              value = _value;
                            }),
                          },
                          hint: Text('Sandwiches')
                        //This hint displays on your drop-box before you open it to see the items list
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex:3,
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          items: [
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "1",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Quantum Burger'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "2",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Cheeseburger'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "3",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Double Cheeseburger 1/4'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "4",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Hamburger 1/4'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "5",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Cheeseburger'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "6",
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Veggie Burger'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                          onChanged: (_value) => {
                            print(_value.toString()),
                            setState(() {
                              value = _value;
                            }),
                          },
                          hint: Text('Burgers')),
       
 ),
```

This is my hashMap file:

```
List<String> sandwich = ["Veggie Melt", "Crispy Chicken Wrap", "Italian Meatball Sub",
  "Chicken Parm Grinder", "Grill Cheese", "Grilled Ham & Cheese", "Bacon Bagel Melt"];
List<double> sandwichPrice = [4.50, 6.95, 6.99, 6.59, 3.59, 4.59, 5.29];
Map<String, double> map1 = Map.fromIterables(sandwich, sandwichPrice);

List<String> burgers = ["Veggie Burger", "The Quantum Burger", "Cafe Melt",
  "The Bull Rider", "Double Cheese Burger", "Hamburger"];
List<double> burgerPrice = [4.99, 7.25, 6.59, 5.79, 5.89, 3.99, 3.79];
Map<String, double> map2 = Map.fromIterables(burgers, burgerPrice);

List<String> otherItems = ["Chicken Quesadilla", "Cheese Quesadilla",
  "Chicken Strips", "Popcorn Chicken", "Jalapeno Poppers"];
List<double> otherItemsPrice = [6.79, 6.29, 4.99, 4.59, 3.49];
Map<String, double> map3 = Map.fromIterables(otherItems, otherItemsPrice);

List<String> sides = ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Jalapeno Cheese Curds",
  "Tater Tots", "Pretzel Bites", "Nachos & Cheese"];
List<double> sidesPrice = [3.29, 4.79, 4.99, 3.19, 4.59, 3.50];
Map<String, double> map4 = Map.fromIterables(sides, sidesPrice);

List<String> pizza = ["7-inch Cheese", "7-inc with topping"];
List<double> pizzaPrice = [4.59, 4.99];
Map<String, double> map5 = Map.fromIterables(pizza, pizzaPrice);

class Menu {
  String sandwich;
  String burger;
  String otherItems;
  String sides;
  String pizza;
  double sandwichPrice;
  double burgerPrice;
  double otherItemsPrice;
  double sidesPrice;
  double pizzaPrice;

  Menu.s(this.sandwich, this.sandwichPrice){}
  Menu.b(this.burger, this.burgerPrice){}
  Menu.o(this.otherItems, this.otherItemsPrice){}
  Menu.q(this.sides, this.sidesPrice){}
  Menu.p(this.pizza, this.pizzaPrice){}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to import your `hashMap` file. Then update your `MyWidget` as follows:

I have displayed here an example of how you can use the `Dropdown` with `map1` (i.e, Sandwiches).

You have to just iterate over the keys of the hashmap 'map1' & create the list of `DropdownMenuItem` from it & pass this list to the `items` property.

For each dropdown, you will need to save the selected option, so instead of using `String value = '';`, I have changed it to `String selectedSandwich = 'Sandwiches';`. This part is crucial as the `Dropdown` widget can have its value only as one of the options available. So, if you do not have the `Sandwiches` option in your dropdown list, there will be an error. Hence, I have added the `Sandwiches` option in the `initState` of your `MyAppWidget`.

You have to do the same for the remaining of the hashmaps. Let me know if you need any more help.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  // Instead of value use selectedSandwich
  String selectedSandwich = 'Sandwiches';

  // List of sandwiches, you have to do the same for rest of the maps
  // like: burgers, otherItems etc.
  List<String> sandwiches = map1.keys.toList();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Adding sandwiches as an option is necessay as the dropdown's value
    // must be equal to one of its options.
    // I have done this only for sandwiches, but you need to do the same
    // for rest.
    sandwiches.insert(0, 'Sandwiches');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          DropdownButton<String>(
            items: sandwiches // using map1.keys.toList
                .map(
                  (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: e,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(e),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (_value) => {
              print(_value.toString()),
              setState(() {
                selectedSandwich = _value; // Set selected sandwich
              }),
            },
            value: selectedSandwich, // Use value
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense however. I do have a question since the hashMap has two components/parameters a String and a double do I just change the double to a string or should the information already be changes or sent when the map1 was imported into the main class. Or do I need to do another step to make the Price of the items show up and what not.

Comment: I think the dropdown that you wanted was consisting only of the keys of the `Map`. That's why I used `map1.keys.toList()`. However, this is not an efficient way. Instead of creating a `Map`, it would be really great if you created a custom model class with these properties. If you want to show details about the price also, then you can easily convert them to string. Also, please provide specific details about what exactly you want to achieve? I will be able to answer it much better.

Comment: For the Futter program we were trying to create 3 pages that connect using a button and 2 of those would be using the Maps or file outside of those 3 main pages. I guess I was trying to make it easier to use the Map or access it and I did at one point think about using a class hence why on my second file shown on the top I created a class Menu. However, in flutter I dont now how to access it within other classes/dart filed or if I have to create it within the main page and the other 2 pages.  I keep wanting to instantiate or call it using Java coding but I know that is wrong too.